# How to write UIWebView with default request address is like (192.168.1.1)

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have implemented UIWebView in my application but i default address is "192.168.1.1" but it is not open default it and i have tried with "http://www.google.com" it is working fine.

```
[iview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"192.168.1.1"]]];
```

it doesn't working and it is working with

```
[iview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `http://` in front of the ip address.

Answer (score 1):

192.168.1.1 isn't a valid URL. Have you tried http://192.168.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to open? Assuming you want to request something from a webserver running at 192.168.1.1...

The scheme part is missing. 
Check if [NSURL URLWithString:@"192.168.1.1"] returns nil. You need to pass a string that conforms to [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.1 is an ip address, http://192.168.1.1 is a URL. Use the later.